# Is it possible to Geo-Target Facebook tabs through facebooks API?

Tags: facebook, api, tabs, location, geotargetting

There's a post addressing this over a year ago, but with all the new changes to the API and facebook constantly putting out new things, I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to Geo-target a facebook tab using Facebook's built in functionality?